# send and receive data using usb to rs232 interface in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am writing c code to send and receive characters to and from an Ergometer using FTDI USB to RS232 Cable in Linux. The write function is working properly but the read function has failed. I am not getting any data back from the Ergometer. I have posted my code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <stdbool.h>


#define SOH 0x01         // Start of Header 
#define ETB 0x17         // End of transmission block
#define ACK 0x06         // Acknowledged
#define NAK 0x15         // Not Acknowledged   
#define GS  0x1D         // Group separator    
#define FP_WATT1_PROG   0x13
#define FP_CARDIO  0x2F

 int main(){

/* Open File Descriptor */
int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY );

/* Error Handling */
if ( USB < 0 )
{
printf("Error beim oeffnen");
}

  // Configure Port 
struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

// Error Handling
if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 ) {
   printf("error beim tcgetattr");
}

// Save old tty parameters 
tty_old = tty;

// Set Baud Rate of 9600 Bps 
cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

// 8 Bits, No Parity and 1 Stop bit settings
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // No Parity
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;            // 1 Stop Bit
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;                // 8 Bits

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
tty.c_cflag     |=  (CLOCAL | CREAD );    // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

// Make raw 
cfmakeraw(&tty);


// Flush Port, then apply attributes 
tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0)
{
printf("from tcsetattr");
}

// WRITE 
    // Set the Ergometer language. 
char cmd[255] = {0x60,0x01};  // Ergometer Cockpit Adresse  

int n_written = write( USB, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
      printf("%s\n",cmd);
    // Allocate memory for read buffer


 int bb = 0;
 int i,x = 0;
 bool cmdOK=false;
 char marr[10];

  do
   {

    if((bb = read(USB, &marr[x], sizeof( marr )-x )) > 0)
   {
     for (i=x;i<x+bb;i++)
     {

      //printf("0x%02x",marr[i]);
      if ((marr[i]==ACK)||(marr[i]==NAK)) cmdOK=true;
    }
  x+=bb;
  //printf("\n");
  //printf("x=%d\n",x);
    }

   }while(!cmdOK);

    printf("-Ausgabe---------------------\n");
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
      printf("0x%02x",marr[i]);
    }
    close(USB);

    // ttyUSB0 auf alten Wert setzen
    tcflush(USB,TCIFLUSH);
    if (tcsetattr(USB, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) return(-1);


    exit(0);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I see your serial port setting is 8n1 using device /dev/ttyUSB0. Does the device answer anything when you send your command using another program like screen, minicom or cutecom?

Comment: the device does not answer anything when i use minicom...

Comment: Is there any chance the device is not working? What about the rs232 cable? Make sure your PC's tx is attached to the rx of your device